# What does the term Tenant refers to in a multi-tenant app data-model?

Tags: database-design, data-modeling, saas, multi-tenant

By multi-tenancy we mean an application serving to different organizations or tenants. Is this tenant just a user or an organization under which there are many users and a complete system? How we set scope for different users under a tenant? their domain of scope is which is allowed to tenant?

Comment: Too broad - There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By multi-tenancy we mean an application serving to different
>   organizations or tenants. Is this tenant just a user or an
>   organization under which there are many users and a complete system?

Tenant Refers to individual Company or organizations who have purchased a paid subscription from the provider/ISV. Ultimately, the respective companies employees who are going to use the application end of the day.

> How we set scope for different users under a tenant? their domain of
>   scope is which is allowed to tenant?

Data Scoping or Entitlement is a must have feature that has to be provided by the product. Many SaaS Solution offers dynamic User and Roles Creation in the application by the Tenants, but not all users are same or have equal priorities in the organization, so the Tenant Administrator must be given with capabilities to assign who can do what as soon a role gets created, this step refers to Data Entitlement.

Comment: What is the description of a tenant in a multi-tenant application according to a developer? :)

Answer (score 0):

to be clear single tenant architecture in database means every client has their own database separate from each other. multi-tenancy means you have one large database for the whole application and database information is segregated in multiple ways.
Now there are several ways of doing this

1. **table level:** you can have a column called tenant_id which references
   tenants table and check to make sure your application shows the data
   belonging to the tenant using it.
2. **Schema level:** Using some RDBMSs like Postgres you can separate each tenant with
   schemas